# How to create a 'file' model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

So I have built an API using Ruby/Sinatra and MondoDB. I'm now writing an Admin panel using Rails that connects to the same database. One of our collections is named 'files' since we need to model an object of such kind in our API. Now, when I wanted to create the File model in the Admin Panel, I came across the fact that I can't create a class called 'File'. Doing so results in the error attached [image]

Even 'File1' is an acceptable class name. How do I now create the File model in my Rails app? I'm using Rails 5.0.0.1.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that is happening because File is a reserve Rails word. I would probably rename the model to something like `FileResource` .

List of Reserved words: http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words

Answer (score 3):

The `file` is ruby's class, you can't and should't use the name in model. Or you will replace the original `File` .

`FileResource` is a good name!